# django how to group on ManyToMany relationship dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have what I believe is a simple request but I have been beating my head against a wall and I am not getting any smarter for it.

I am using django 1.10. What I am trying to do is get a list of my members grouped by my family field

The models look like this:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User)
    family = models.ManyToManyField(Family,blank=True,related_name='members')
```

So i can set my view to use

```
members = Member.objects.order_by('family')
```

or

```
members = Family.objects.order_by('family_name')
```

This obviously holds my members or my families but not both. How would i get this to have both the member name and their family and then group by it?

An Example of the output i am looking for is:

Family 1

- Member 1
- Member 2

Family 2

- Member 1
- Member 3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the first one? If you want to order it by the family's `name`, do:

```
members = Member.objects.order_by('family__family_name')
```

These members all have their family available via `.family`. If you want to save db queries when you are looping through these members and access their families, you can add a [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
members = Member.objects.order_by('family__family_name').select_related('family')
```

On the other hand, if you really want families and then loop through their members, do:

```
families = Family.objects.order_by('family_name').prefetch_related('members')
for fam in families:
    // do sth. with family
    for mem in fam.members.all():
        // do sth. with member
```

The [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) will make this run with only 2 db queries, no matter how many families or members.

Comment: @schwobaseggle The results for this would be the same as what I am already getting. I think you are on the right point where .family is what i need but not sure how to get it. I have added an example to my question to see if that helps how to get there.

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid but how would i build this into a query set where i have families with their members that I can pull from a nested for loop in the same manner to be be used in a template?

Comment: Not sure if I get you :) You can pass the `families` QS to the template context and just use nested template loops á la: `{% for fam in families %}..{% for mem in fam.members.all %}...{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`